# Apache2.4.10 custom error page

Tags: html, apache, debian

So, I'm trying to set up a simple site, but I can't get my custom error pages to show up. Does anyone have any way to do this?

Using Apache2.4.10 on Debian

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest taking a look at the ErrorDocument directive and configure the proper error code to your custom page: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Also you might want to check where in your config files you want to do that, either in the main apache conf, either in your website conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Your question is too vague to give a more detailed answer, but the documentation link above should help you get this done.